# foreach variable undefined in laravel

Tags: variables, foreach, undefined

I'm getting the error that $recipient variable is undefined in laravel.

```
public function sendEmail($input, $recipients){

    foreach($recipients as $recipient){
            $student = StudentInfo::where('email', '=', $recipient)->first(); 
            Mail::queue('emails.outMail', array('letter' => $input['dept_message']), function($message){
                $message->to($recipient, $student->first_name)->subject($input['dept_subject']);
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Add full trace of error.

Answer (score -1):

In the closure function, you need to use $recipient.

```
    function($message) use ($recipient){

         //code

    }
```

Updated Code

---

```
public function sendEmail($input, $recipients){
    foreach($recipients as $recipient){
            $student = StudentInfo::where('email', '=', $recipient)->first(); 
            Mail::queue('emails.outMail', array('letter' => $input['dept_message']), function($message) use ($recipient) {
                $message->to($recipient, $student->first_name)->subject($input['dept_subject']);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi ibnkashmir, welcome to Stack Overflow! I wonder if you could edit your answer to make it clear what the difference is between your code and the original code. It took a while for me to spot the extra `use ($recipient)`. It will help the original poster but also anyone who finds this page later!